# Infinite decomposition of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection, direct-sum

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose we have $H_{n}\oplus G_{n}=H$  for all $%
n\geq 0$ so that $\left( H_{n}\right) _{n\geq 0}$ is an increasing sequence
of closed subspaces and $\left( G_{n}\right) _{n\geq 0}$ is a decreasing
sequence of closed subspaces. I think we don't have in general : $H=%
\overline{\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcup }H_{n}}+\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcap }%
G_{n}$. My question is do we have : $H=\overline{\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcup 
}H_{n}+\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcap }G_{n}}$ ? This statement looks simple
but seems to me hard to be confirmed or even disproved with a
counter-example.

Comment: Are you assuming $H_n\perp G_n?$

Comment: No. It would be easy

Comment: Wlog, $\bigcap G_n$ is $\{0\}$ (because we can quotient everything by it). So, it would suffice to confirm your intuition "I think we don't have in general : $H=
\overline{\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcup }H_{n}}+\underset{n\geq 0}{\bigcap }
G_{n}$" by some counterexample.